# Reducing Space Between Graphics

Tags: spacing

I have about a half page of space between my two graphics: I want them to be closer together. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2.0in]{linear.png}
        \caption{$\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ $= 0.3$}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~ 
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2.0in]{exponential.png}
        \caption{$\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ $= 0.81$}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Small $x[0]$}
\addtolength{\textfloatsep}{-0.2in}
\end{figure}

\FloatBarrier
This behavior could be due to $y'[t]$ decreasing in value quickly with large $y[0], \delta_{1}$, and $\delta_{2}$ and $x'[t]$ then increasing in value as the $-\delta_{2}y$ decreases in absolute value while the denominator, $1-\delta_{1}$ is small, causing $x[t]$ to increase faster.

For $x_[0] = .45$, we see similar behavior as we adjust our deltas, but $x[t]$ is monotone decreasing.
\begin{figure}
    \centering

    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2.0in]{LowD.png}
        \caption{$\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ $= 0.3$}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~ 
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2.0in]{HigherD.png}
        \caption{$\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ $= 0.81$}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Large $x[0]$}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier

\end{document}
```

How can I conserve the space in the middle of my page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the second figure to be close to the text if you add the `!htbp`-option.

```
\documentclass[notitlepage]{report}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry} 
\usepackage{enumitem} 
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\topfraction}{0.45}


\begin{document}


\begin{figure}
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2.0in]{1}
        \caption{$\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ $= 0.3$}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~ 
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2.0in]{1}
        \caption{$\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ $= 0.81$}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Small $x[0]$}
\addtolength{\textfloatsep}{-0.2in}
\end{figure}


\FloatBarrier
This behavior could be due to $y'[t]$ decreasing in value quickly with large $y[0], \delta_{1}$, and $\delta_{2}$ and $x'[t]$ then increasing in value as the $-\delta_{2}y$ decreases in absolute value while the denominator, $1-\delta_{1}$ is small, causing $x[t]$ to increase faster.

For $x_[0] = .45$, we see similar behavior as we adjust our deltas, but $x[t]$ is monotone decreasing.
\begin{figure}[!htbp]
    \centering

    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2.0in]{1}
        \caption{$\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ $= 0.3$}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~ 
    \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \includegraphics[height=2.0in]{1}
        \caption{$\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ $= 0.81$}
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Large $x[0]$}
\end{figure}
\FloatBarrier

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

- you not need to use `\FloatBarrier`
- to float `figure` add option for its placement `[ht]` (as also suggested @Jan in [his answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/503217/reducing-space-between-graphics/503219#503219))
- reduce width of `subcption` from `0.5` to for example `0.4`
- for space between sub figures use `\hfil`
- remove `\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{-10pt}` from `figure` or move it to document preamble

```
\documentclass[notitlepage, demo]{report}% in real document delete option demo
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{placeins}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics[height=2.0in]{linear.png}
\caption{$\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ $= 0.3$}
\end{subfigure}%
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics[height=2.0in]{exponential.png}
\caption{$\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ $= 0.81$}
    \end{subfigure}
\caption{Small $x[0]$}
\end{figure}
%\FloatBarrier
This behavior could be due to $y'[t]$ decreasing in value quickly with large $y[0], \delta_{1}$, and $\delta_{2}$ and $x'[t]$ then increasing in value as the $-\delta_{2}y$ decreases in absolute value while the denominator, $1-\delta_{1}$ is small, causing $x[t]$ to increase faster.

For $x_[0] = .45$, we see similar behavior as we adjust our deltas, but $x[t]$ is monotone decreasing.
    \begin{figure}[ht]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics[height=2.0in]{LowD.png}
\caption{$\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ $= 0.3$}
    \end{subfigure}
    \hfil
    \begin{subfigure}{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
\includegraphics[height=2.0in]{HigherD.png}
\caption{$\delta_{1}$ and $\delta_{2}$ $= 0.81$}
    \end{subfigure}
    \caption{Large $x[0]$}
\end{figure}
%\FloatBarrier

\end{document}
```